# Connected my keyboard to Apple 67W USB-C Power Adapter: Voltage Concerns

Tags: voltage, usb, usb-c, keyboard, usb-pd

I recently had an experience with my keyboard (HHKB Professional Hybrid Type S) that I wanted to get some additional insights on.

Specifically, I accidentally connected my keyboard to a 67W Apple USB-C power adapter for a brief duration of about 30 seconds. Post this, the keyboard seems to function perfectly fine.

From what I understand, USB-C Power Delivery has a negotiation process to determine the right voltage for connected devices.

The Apple charger has multiple output voltages, but without a request for higher voltages, it defaults to supplying 5V.

I reached out to RICOH/Fujitsu regarding my concerns, and they indicated that the HHKB supports only 5V. They stated that while there is no protection circuit, if a voltage higher than 5V is applied, the HHKB's circuit could be damaged. This understanding accentuates my concern about the slight 0.2V difference in the Apple charger's output.

Additionally, the Apple charger's lowest voltage output is actually 5.2V.

This brings me to a key question: Does a slight voltage difference of 0.2V have any significant impact on devices designed for 5V?

for peace of mind, I wanted to gather opinions from the community.

Is there a reason for concern regarding potential internal damage that isn't immediately visible? Does the USB-C PD protocol ensure that such mistakes won't harm devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB's basic voltage spec is 5V *plus or minus 5%*. That's 4.75 to 5.25 volts. Any compliant USB device should therefore be tolerant of 5.25 at least.

In fact it's common for designers of higher-power chargers (including Apple) to build them for an open-circuit voltage of 5.2V. This leaves less wiggle room for regulation issues with the charger, but it means that there will still be 5V, even at the end of a long(ish) cable, even when a device is drawing high current. This is something that's been done for at least 10 years now.

When the HHKB manufacturer says not to go above 5V they mean by more than the 5% margin — particularly, don't apply 9V, 12V, or 20V. But that's not something that's likely to happen unless you go out of your way to make it happen.